# Swagger/OpenAPI API Specification: how do I (properly) keep a Changelog?

Tags: swagger, openapi, changelog

I'm providing an OpenAPI 3.0 file as an API specification in JSON format. I expect the APIs to be updated quite regularly and want to keep readers informed of changes made.

I noted that there's a "version" attribute in "info" which can be used to indicate versioning, but is there a dedicated/prefered field to keep a changelog of the versions?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
V0.1.1 - 2022/11/25
- added "gender" attribute to response of "/getPersonalDetails"
- changed "record_dt" format of "/getPersonalDetails" from "YYYY-MM-DD" to "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"

V0.1.2 - 2022/11/26
- other changes...
```

The only appropriate (or possible) location I've found so far within the document itself is the "description" fields, to either dump all changelog in "info/description" or increment version number and write API-specific changelogs in the API descriptions. I just worry either way could seem too messy as the versions stack.

SwaggerHub does provide a versioning tool but it requires a subscription and also I want to share the document in JSON which can be consumed as a standalone file.

Comment: Related: [Does Open API 3.0 specification support changelogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63414846/113116)

Comment: Oh right, yes it is the same topic. Sorry that I overlooked it.